# How to set focus to a cell in Pyqt5 Table Widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, widget, focus

I'm using pyqt5, Table Widget, and Python. Everything is working fine with my code, but I can't figure out how to set focus to a particular cell (or any cell). If my table looks like the below table, how do it set focus to a particular cell? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNO97.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [`setCurrentCell()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCurrentCell).